# Plotting shapefile Error in loops

Tags: r, plot, gis, shapefile

I am trying to make a plot of 12 ecoregions which come as shapefiles. 
As an example:

```
ER_10.2<-Level.2.ecoregs[Level.2.ecoregs$NA_L2CODE=="10.2",]
> ER_10.2
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
nfeatures   : 26 
extent      : -1693158, 44930.55, -2591002, -691719.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs 
nvariables  : 8
names       : NA_L2CODE,    NA_L2NAME, NA_L1CODE,              NA_L1NAME,           NA_L2KEY,                   NA_L1KEY,  Shape_Leng,   Shape_Area 
min values  :      10.2, WARM DESERTS,        10, NORTH AMERICAN DESERTS, 10.2  WARM DESERTS, 10  NORTH AMERICAN DESERTS,    11613.69,      8382714 
max values  :      10.2, WARM DESERTS,        10, NORTH AMERICAN DESERTS, 10.2  WARM DESERTS, 10  NORTH AMERICAN DESERTS, 11456404.58, 510159399963
```

I need to do this in a loop because I am also including additional analyses.

```
Ecoregions.list <- c("ER_10.2", "ER_12.1", "ER_14.3","ER_13.2",
  "ER_09.6", "ER_09.5", "ER_14.1", "ER_13.3", "ER_09.4", "ER_08.3", "ER_13.1", "ER_11.1")

Ecoregions<-unique(as.character(Ecoregions.list))

for(i in 1:length(Ecoregions))
    {
    Ecoregions<-unique(as.character(Ecoregions.list))
    ER=as.name(Ecoregions[i])
    plot (ER)
    }
```

But when I try to read in the figure to plot it, I always get this error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : invalid first argument
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the loop is the best practice in this situation, but using `as.name` in your current code is causing you grief I believe.

There is also no need to loop over `1:length(x)`, the `for` statement will just iteratively go through each element of a vector like `Ecoregions` without being explicitly told to do so.

Try something like this simplified example instead, using `get`:

```
ER_10.2 <- data.frame(v1=1:10)
ER_12.1 <- data.frame(v1=2:11)
Ecoregions.list <- c("ER_10.2", "ER_12.1")
Ecoregions <- unique(Ecoregions.list)

for(i in Ecoregions) {
    ER <- get(i)[[1]]
    # add the below line if you want 12 separate plots
    # dev.new() 
    plot(ER)
    # insert other code here which would presumably negate
    # your ability to use the 'lapply' function.
}
```

I should note additionally that it is typically not a good idea in R to use functions like `get` and text strings to represent names of data. Normally, if you have many related `data.frames` or other objects, you would put them together in a `list` like:

```
Ecoregions <- list(ER_10.2, ER_12.1)
```

Which allows you to then apply functions to each component using `lapply` or `sapply` like so:

```
lapply(Ecoregions,function(x) plot(x[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't want to use `as.name`, but I think you are looking for something like `get`. So, just replace `ER=as.name(Ecoregions[i])` with `ER=get(Ecoregions[i])` and it should work.

But this isn't a really great way of handling this situation. Instead of making a new variable for each of your regions, you can make a `list` of regions. That way, you loop through the `list` elements rather than the variable names.

For example, instead of `ER_10.2<-Level.2.ecoregs[Level.2.ecoregs$NA_L2CODE=="10.2",]` try doing something like:

```
# Split your regions by the L2 Code.
list.of.regions<-split(Level.2.ecoregs,Level.2.ecoregs$NA_L2CODE)
```

Now, if your data changes (like if a new `NA_L2CODE` is added), you won't have to change your code, because it will be a new element of your list.

Now, you can loop over elements of your list:

```
# Loop over each element of the list.
for (region in list.of.regions) 
    plot(region)
```

And, if you wanted to get fancy, you could use `lapply`, which just runs a function on each element of a `list`.

```
lapply(list.of.regions,plot)
```

If you wanted to get even fancier, though, and you wanted to make a plot of all the regions in a grid, you could use `lattice` or `ggplot`. Try looking up `ggmap` for some nice examples.